# How tall is the ladder?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater

In Snake Eater, there is one ladder which is much longer than others. It occurs after the boss fight with The End, as Snake is about to enter the mountain area:

In meters, feet, and game units, how large is this ladder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to user *DrkAndStormy* on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/metalgearsolid/comments/4ltfb1/the_ladder_of_snake_eater/), **it's about 412 feet (125 meters) high**:

> After looking closely at footage and playing it back and what not, it
>   turns out Naked Snake makes his way up 3 bars in a single second. The
>   entire climb takes 1 minute and 47 seconds. After a bit of math,
>   you'll find Snake climbed a total of 321 bars. If Naked Snake is 6'5",
>   then that means he is roughly [the height of 5 bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHxxj.jpg) on the ladder. With the knowledge that there are 321
>   bars, and each 5 bars are roughly 77 inches tall, we can say Naked
>   Snake climbed 411.95 feet worth of ladder.

That's assuming a lot of variables, but seems to be a decent estimate.

Also [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOrnU.jpg).

Comment: Naked Snake is 6'5" when hunched over like that? Is that canon? That seems very tall, especially since Eva is roughly the same height. https://misterblank22.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/ose164_-_snake_y_eva.png

Comment: There having that discussion in the same thread, some people arguing that Naked Snake is considered 5'11''. If that is the case, the stairs are more like 380 feet/116 meters high. So **120 meters should be an acceptable average**.

Answer (score 3):

In the video we can see the following: 306 steps were climbed, going by sound. Standing, Snake is 4,5 steps high. Snake is 1,92m tall according to canon.
So... 306/4.5 = 68 Snakes. 68*1,92 = 130,56m. 
Accounting for errors, we'll round up, so roughly, the ladder is 131m, or 430ft.